# PropertyRef on a HasManyToMany Relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there a way to specify a `PropertyRef` on a many to many relationship using FluentNhibernate?

I have 3 tables

> 1. Event(id, ...)
> 2. EventOnline(id, eventId, onlineId)
> 3. Online(id, code, ...)

On the EventOnline table I connect to the Online table via its "code" column instead of Id. If this was a regular one-to-one relationship I would do something like

```
References(x => x.Online, "onlineId").PropertyRef("Code");
```

in the EventOnlineMap.

But I want to represent this as a many-to-many relationship in in the EventMapping.

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Onlines).Table("EventOnline").ParentKeyColumn("EventId").ChildKeyColumn("OnlineId").LazyLoad().AsSet().Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughLowerCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

The problem is I can't specify `PropertyRef("code")` on the HasManyToMany construct. This attribute does exist if I was to do the mapping in xml.

```
<set name="Onlines" table="EventOnline" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" schema="EventsCalendar.dbo" lazy="true">
     <key column="eventId"></key>
     <many-to-many class="CommonLookupService.Data.Domain.Online, CommonLookupService.Data" column="onlineId" property-ref="Code"></many-to-many>
</set>
```

So the question is.... What is the equivalent of PropertyRef on a HasManyToMany construct in FluentNhibernate?

Comment: What version of FluentNhibernate are you using? I have 1.2 and there is a PropertyRef method on the ManyToManyPart.

Comment: We are using version 1.0. I am not sure if we can use 1.2 with nhibernate 2.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, FluentNHibernate is open source so you can build it yourself using NHibernate 2.1

Comment: Right... I was hoping for a more hands off solution.

Comment: That's the only solution other than using hbm files. There's no manual way of setting properties in FNH.

Answer (score 1):

`HasManyToMany().ChildPropertyRef().PropertyRef()` is implemented in FNH 1.1 which is compiled against NH 2.1